# Given an directed acyclic graph, create a strategy so that there is a bidirectional path between all possible Vertices

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, graph-theory, directed-graph, edges

### Given an directed acyclic graph, create a strategy so that there is a bidirectional path between all possible Vertices

You can attain this by adding edges. Propose a strategy for solving this with adding as little edges as possible
A Vertice on the input graph can be without edges.

EXAMPLE:
[image: input acyclic directed graph]
To solve this graph the most efficient way, we need to add ONLY 2 edges:
[image: solved directed graph with every vertice having biderectional path to another vertice]

Keep in mind that the algorithm doesn't need to be perfect, also NO NEED to code anything (unless you want to:)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a DAG that has m vertices with in-degree 0 and n vertices with out-degree 0:

Obviously, you will need to add m edges incoming to the in-degree 0 vertices, and n edges outgoing from the out-degree 0 vertices, so the best you can hope for is max(m,n) new edges.  We can achieve this.

First, if m > n, then connect in-degree 0 vertices until m = n.  Otherwise connect out-degree 0 vertices until m = n.

Now we have m=n, which we will maintain:

- Find a vertex with in-degree 0 that *doesn't* reach all the vertices with out-degree 0.  If there isn't one, then connect out-degree 0 vertices arbitrarily to in-degree 0 vertices and you're all done.
- Otherwise, connect an out-degree 0 vertex that it *does* reach to an in-degree 0 vertex that reaches an out-degree 0 vertex that it *doesn't* reach.  This reduces m and n by 1.
- Repeat until you're done.

Comment: Valid answer, thank you! How would this theory change, if the input graph wasn't acyclic?

Comment: If the graph isn't acyclic, then you can use Tarjan's algorithm to find all the strongly connected components, and collapse each one into a single vertex to form an acyclic graph.  Then run this algorithm.